# TypeError: has no method 'isAbsolute'

Tags: css, gulp, minify, gulp-clean-css, gulp-minify-css

I want to minify any css in my folder, where i use gulp-clean-css plugin for gulp.

**My code is:**

```
gulp.task('CSS-Pack', function () {
    return gulp.src(['Content/App.css', './Content/ApprovalForm.css'])
               .pipe(concat('stylesheets.css'))
               .pipe(cleanCSS({ debug: true }, function (details) {
                   console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
                   console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
               }))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});


gulp.task('CSS-PackAll', function () {
    return gulp.src('Content/*.css')
               .pipe(concat('stylesheets.css'))
               .pipe(cleanCSS({ debug: true, specialComments: false }, function (details) {
                   console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
                   console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
               }))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

My task **CSS-Pack** works, but where i start task **CSS-PackAll** i have following error:

Where i use minify-css(i want to use gulp-clean-css, because minify-css is depricated) plugin **CSS-PackAll** working..

> :\Users\gkv\TFS\SharePoint Online\LirexAddHolidayRequest\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\rewrite-url.js:45
>     return path.isAbsolute(uri);
>                 ^
>   **TypeError: Object # has no method 'isAbsolute'**
>       at isAbsolute (C:\Users\gstev\TFS\SharePoint Online\LirexAddHolidayRequest\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\rewrite-url.js:45:15)
>       at rebase (C:\Users\gkrystev\TFS\SharePoint Online\LirexAddHolidayRequest\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\rewrite-url.js:23:7)
>       at rewriteUrl (C:\Users\gkrystev\TFS\SharePoint Online\LirexAddHolidayRequest\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\rewrite-url.js:114:5)
>       at rebaseSourceMapComment (C:\Users\gkrystev\TFS\SharePoint Online\LirexAddHolidayRequest\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\rebase.js:78:45)
>   Process terminated with code 8.

Comment: Can you try a couple of things? Use `'Content/*.css'` in your `CSS-Pack` task and see what happens. Also, try removing the extra configuration parameter `specialComments` which was a braking change from the previous version in your `CSS-PackAll` task.

Comment: I have in folder bootstrap css files Content/*.css

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that strictly speaking this isn't an answer to your problem, but I hit this exact error when using gulp-clean-css to minify our CSS and tracked the problem to a single line in our source:

```
background-image: url('/img/cloader.gif') no-repeat center top;
```

It appears to be a problem processing a relative URL; in our case, we no longer needed this style and removing it resolved the problem. Hope this helps.